# OO(object-oriented) javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I've a fair amount of experience with JavaScript, and for this new project I'm on (cms for blog with notions of profitability) I thought I'd step it up and write the JavaScript in an MVC fashion. I've been using a bit of backbone and underscore, but it isn't clicking mentally. any way, I've written a bit of code to handle some events/effects but it just doesn't work. If anyone could sort me out I'd really appreciate it.

```
// Semi Perfect grade 0 JS - Golden age
//partial View Objects | Events
var pshare_dock = {
    actor: $("#share_dock"),
    drag: function () {
        this.actor.draggable();
    }
}
pshare_dock.expand = function () {
    this.actor.dblclick(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("share_close");
    });
}
var pmenu = {
    hover: function () {
        $("ul.drop li.drop").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(1);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('ul').hide();
        })
    },
    navigate: function () {
        $("a.ajx").click(function (e) {
            var link;
            var container = $("#content_pane");
            e.preventDefault();
            link = $(this).attr("href") + "#content_pane";
            container.load(link);
        })
    }
}
var pcontent_pane = {}
var ppost = {}
var pdatabase_entry = {}
//Views
var Homepage = function () {
        this.share_dock = function () {
            new pshare_dock();
        }
        this.menu = function () {
            new pmenu();
        }
        this.content_pane = function () {
            new pcontent_pane();
        }
        this.posts = function () {
            new ppost();
        }
    }
    //Controller
var GoldenAgeRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "!/": "defaultRoute",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },
    defaultRoute: function (actions) {
        var homeView = function () {
                new Homepage();
            }
    }
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Golden_age = function () {
            new Homepage();
        }
})
```

the question is essentially what all is wrong with this?

Comment: The term 'object oriented javascript' is redundant like saying 'alcoholic vodka'

Comment: @AlienWebguy A fair share of people favor the functional paradigm and only use objects as data structures. And then there's the ton of people who just write an unholy mess using neither objects nor functions to their full extend.

Comment: Functions are objects. Everything is an object in JavaScript, that's my point. `​document.write("hello world".length)​​​​​​​​; // 11`

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping your instantiations in an anonymous function but not invoking them:

```
var Golden_age = new Homepage(); // Invoked.

var Golden_age = function(){ new Homepage(); } // Stored function, not invoked.
```